# How to implement an accurate, cross-platform game loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, timer

I'm trying to implement a game loop at runs every 10ms on both node.js and in modern web browsers. This version runs fine in Chrome (stays within 1ms accuracy):

```
var nextUpdate = Date.now();
function loop() {
  console.log(Date.now());
  // update() here
  nextUpdate += 10; // ms
  setTimeout(loop, Math.max(0, nextUpdate - Date.now()));
}
loop();
```

However, setTimeout is much less accurate in Firefox and node.js. Even a 0ms timeout takes longer than 10ms on average to execute, which causes the loop to go out of sync completely.

What is a better way to implement an accurate, cross-platform game loop in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers support high precision timers with the `Performance` API.
Look at these links:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance

http://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/#sec-DOMHighResTimeStamp

Comment: It's useful, but I don't see an alternative for setTimeout that can fire under 10ms, and busy-waiting is not an option.